# How to reference an element with spaces in handlebars on node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, handlebars.js, node-modules

I have an object in witch some of the values are strings containing spaces. Something like this:

```
object = {
 "group of people": [
  {
   (...)
  }
 ],
 "another group of people": [
  {
   (...)
  }
 ]
}
```

And I'm trying to use it with the handlebars helper block in my view (index.hbs) like this:

```
{{#each group of people}}
 (...)
{{/each}}
```

But I get an error (of course), because of the spaces on "group of people". I've tried the following cases without any success:

```
{{#each "group of people"}}
{{#each 'group of people'}}
{{#each group%20of%20people}}
{{#each groupofpeople}}
{{#each group&nbsp;of&nbsp;people}}
```

Any idea on how to get this working?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To use a property that has spaces, you can decorate it with `[]`.
e.g.
Given helpers:

```
obj = {
  'property with spaces': 'hello'
};
```

Template:

```
<p>{{[property with spaces]}}</p>
```

Would generate:

```
<p>hello</p>
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for the easy and succinct answer! =)

Comment: if you're iterating over loop
{{{ this.[property name with space] }}}

Answer (score 0):

The strings don't matter, they're values to handlebars.  Consider this:

```
  <ul>
    {{#each object}}
      <li>{{@key}}: {{this}}<li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
```

You'll get a set of list items for each key in your object.  The keys like 'group of people' will print out where I've put `@key` and the value for that key will be printed where there is `this`, though in your case that's another array so obviously you'll want to further transform that.

Answer (score 0):

I have something to add 5 years later for whoever gets stuck like me. I struggled to add an object key containing spaces *Spaced Key* as a form name:

```
{{#each ObjectKey}}
<label>{{@key}}<input name={{@key}}></label>
{{/each}}
```

Would render as

```
<label>Spaced Key<input name="Spaced" Key></label>
```

It could not be solved with segment-literal notation [], triple-stash {{{ }}} or both. The only solution was to register a helper

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('setName', function (inputName) {
    return `name="${inputName}"`;
});
```

Then set the template as such

```
{{#each ObjectKey}}
<label>{{@key}}<input {{{setName @key}}}></label>
{{/each}}
```

Hope that saves someone the hours I spend troubleshooting.